# How lock websocket (or state) connection until scraper's done

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, websocket, socket.io

I have multiple scrapers like below:

```
await scraper1.run
await scraper2.run
// etc
```

to increase performance and response time I used websocket and I pass socket connection down to each scraper and emit for each single item (of the result).

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const cors = require('cors')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const _ = require('lodash')

const scraper1 = require('./scraper1')
const scraper2 = require('./scraper2')

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test")

;(async function () {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    })

    io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
      socket.on('search', async function (query) {
        // check whether document exists with user ip address then return
        // otherwise run the scrapres
        await scraper1.run(browser, socket, query)
        await scraper2.run(browser, socket, query)
      })
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})()

http.listen(3000)
```

**Context**: When user does refresh and multiple socket connections made the scrapers run multiple times and data become duplicate. I prevented the duplication using mongodb but the performance issue remains because scrapers run until their result are ready then I check with the database.

**Question**: How to lock or prevent scrapers from running multiple times and also wait for each scraper to be done with websocket?

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: 1. User connects via websocket, starts scrape(s). 2. as scrapes are progressing, user gets results sent back via same socket. 3. at some point user refreshes browser window, which breaks all websocket connections. 4. new sockets are established after refresh completes, but user isn't seeing updates any more (old sockets are lost). 5. user tries to restart same scrapes over again. Is this it? And the problem(s) you're trying to resolve are 1. you don't want the duplicate scrapes, and 2. user should continue to see their running scrapes after a reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you next solution (I didn't test it but I guess you can figure out what I am trying to achieve, the explanation below the example):

```
'use strict';

const queryState = {

};

const getQueryKey = (query) => {
  // base64 but can be a hash like sha256
  const key = Buffer.from(query).toString('base64');

  return key;
};

/**
 * Return query state
 * @param {String} query
 * @return {String} state [PENDING, DONE, null] null if query doesn't exist
 */
const getQueryState = (query) => {
  const key = getQueryKey(query);

  const state = queryState[key] || null;

  return state;
};

/**
 * Add a query and initialize it as pending
 * @param {String} query
 * @return {String} state
 */
const addQuery = (query) => {
  const key = getQueryKey(query);
  const state = 'PENDING';
  queryState[key] = state;

  return state;
};

/**
 * Hashmap to associate pending queries to be notified to socket connections
 * when query is done
 * This structure keeps and array of callbacks per query key
 */
const observers = {

};

const addObserver = (query, callback) => {
  const key = getQueryKey(query);

  if (typeof observers[key] !== 'undefined') {
    observers[key] = [callback];
  } else {
    observers[key] = [...observers[key], callback];
  }
};

const notifyObservers = (query) => {
  const key = getQueryKey(query);

  const callbacks = observers[key] || [];

  // TODO: get query data scrapper from a cache / database / etc
  const data = getDataFromQuery(query);
  callbacks.forEach((callback) => {
    callback(data);
  });
};

/**
 * Update query status to done
 * PreCD: query must exist in queryState (previously added using addQuery)
 * @param {String} query
 * @return {String} state
 */
const endQuery = (query) => {
  const key = getQueryKey(query);
  const state = 'DONE';
  queryState[key] = state;

  return state;
};

io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
  socket.on('search', async function (query) {
    /**
     * If query doesn't exist, scrap it
     */
    const state = getQueryState(query);
    if (state === null) {
      addQuery(query);
      await scraper1.run(browser, socket, query);
      await scraper2.run(browser, socket, query);
      endQuery(query);

      // store scrapper data in cache / database / etc and
      // socket send scraperData to the user

      // notify pending queries to send data scrapper
      notifyObservers(query);
    } else if (state === 'PENDING') {
      // add callback to return data to the user
      addObserver(query, (scraperData) => {
        // socket send scraperData to the user
      });
    } else {
      // socket send scraperData to the user
    }
  });
});
```

To simplify the things, the example is simple but not the best one in terms of performance / architecture. This solution implements:

Scenario 1 (someone asking for query1 first time)

1. A request (socket connection) came to the backend asking for a query
2. This request doesn't exist yet, so, mark it as PENDING and start scrappers

Scenario 2 (another one asking for query1)

1. A second connection appears asking for same query as scenario 1
2. The request is in state PENDING, so, we add a callback to be call when this query finish

Scenario 3 (query 1 finish)

1. Scrappers started at Scenario 1 ends so query1 is market as DONE
2. Each request (observer) waiting for query1 will be notified

This solution can have multiple ways to be implemented, but my point is try to expose this to you and then you can modify it in the way you want.

Hope this helps